# Issues with importing pylab on Mac OS X 10.8.3

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, osx-mountain-lion

**I get the following error when I import pylab:**

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 225, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/finance.py", line 23, in <module>
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, PolyCollection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/collections.py", line 23, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 50, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1297
    _fc_match_regex = re.compile(rb'\sfile:\s+"([^"]*)"')
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Installed dependancies using homebrew

```
brew install freetype
brew install libpng
```

Installed matplotlib and numpy by cloning the github repo and doing:

```
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Any help in resolving this issues is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you properly format the traceback? Is it even complete? I can't see the exception type.

Comment: Sorry, thx for fixing the format and I added full stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syntax error in that file. I guess you're using the development sources? That `rb` shouldn't be there before the regular expression (it should be `r` in Python 2.x, maybe `b` in Python 3.x).

**UPDATE:** Yep. Here's the faulty commit:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/2415c6200ebdba75a0571d71a4569f18153fff57

Comment: I guess I must be using dev sources; however I did install from the Master branch.

Comment: Master seems to be broken. Either download the tarball, or checkout 1.2.1rc1 or 1.2.0.

Comment: I took the easy way out and just edit the file direct removing the 'b' and it's working now :).

Answer (score 0):

## Trinity:

```
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install matplotlib
sudo pip install scipy
```

If you are using master to compile it run `sudo brew update` and then:

```
sudo brew install freetype
sudo brew install libpng
```

and then build and install:

```
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: OP is using master, which is currently broken. It's not an installation problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `br`.  This will be fixed in matplotlib master momentarily.